# Combine W3 css slider/carousels - multiple images changing automatically

Tags: javascript, css, slider, carousel

W3's [CSS slider page](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp) has examples of two image sliders:

- one that change a single image [automatically on a timer](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_rr);
- and one that displays [two images at once](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_two) but requires a click to display the next image.

I'd like to display a block of four images in a row, that each changes on a timer to an image from the same folder - e.g.

```
+---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |  ->   | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |  ->   | 9 | 10| 11| 12|
+---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+
```

How can I combine the JS code from the two W3 examples to do this?